# strstr() don't work in PHP

Tags: php, strstr

I have this code in PHP with that uses the function, `strstr()`:

```
$conversation = strstr($bash, '_');
$pseudo = strrchr($bash, '_');
//On ajoute les balises html au pseudo et a la conversation
$cherche = array($pseudo, $conversation);
$remplace = array("'<span class=\"pseudo\">' , $pseudo , '</span>'",
                  "'<span class=\"pseudo\">' , $conversation , '</span><br />'");
str_replace($cherche, $remplace , $bash);
echo $bash;
```

However, `echo function display $bash` does not display any error message.

Comment: Use `echo` and `print_r` throughout and figure out which step isn't producing what you think it should be. Basic debugging. We can't debug this without knowing what `$bash` contains, anyways.

Comment: i think it might be your str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace()` RETURNS the modified string, it does not do an in-place change.

```
$new_bash = str_replace($cherche, $remplace, $bash);
```

Comment: work thank you (im so noob...) just lose 1 hour of my time try understanding